# How can I use OR operator with 2 tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to making a search option for my website project. I have to search 2 columns from 2 tables. After that, I'll write that query in my php code. Then it will list all the data about it. But it seems like I'm doing it wrong. What should I do?

```
select *
from mudurler,subeler,veriler
where mudurler.sube_id=subeler.sube_id
and veriler.sube_id=subeler.sube_id
and subeler.sube_ad like "%this%" or mudurler.adSoyad like "%that%"
```

When I go, if there is a valid value on sube_ad it works perfectly. But when i try to put valid value on adSoyad MySQL turns an empty result no matter what the value is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have no problem if you used proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax:

```
select *
from mudurler m join
     subeler s
     on m.sube_id = s.sube_id join
     veriler v
     on v.sube_id = s.sube_id
where s.sube_ad like '%this%' or
      m.adSoyad like '%that%';
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try:
and (subeler.sube_ad like "%this%" or mudurler.adSoyad like "%that%")